# Old pulp sci-fi series from the seventies with many books

Tags: story-identification, books

Back in the late seventies I began collecting a sci-fi series. There were just a ton of them, and they were all pretty standard pulp sci-fi hero stuff, all about the same hero and, I believe, by the same author... someone who later became famous and wrote these under a pseudonym. My mom chucked the books while I was overseas, and I can't remember what they were. I thought it was the *Lucky Star* series by Asimov, but those were only six books.

Comment: Hi, we could really do with a bit more detail. Can you describe the plots of any books? Appearance of central characters, bad guys? There are a lot of series to choose from. That said I'd suggest starting by taking a look at the Perry Rhodan series. Long running pulp fiction as you describe... also take a look at the guidelines on how to write a clear question... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour  good luck, hope you find what you re after.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a bit thin on detail; do you recall any of the covers, any names or plot details?  From what you've said here I can think of 2 possibilities off the top of my head:  E.C. Tubb's *Dumarest* series ran over 30 books from the 60s through the 80s and Perry Rhodan ran to over 100 issues in English translation through the 70s.

Comment: Well, for all of those questions, I still got my answer! Thanks!! It was the Perry Rhodan series!!!

Comment: @vaugnOhlman Nice!  Glad you got an answer.  Deleting my Doc Savage suggestion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggested this in the comments as wild guess as the description was "pulp fiction, long-running from the 1970's" which put in my mind [the *Perry Rhodan* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan). Turned out to be correct as mentioned by the person asking, even though this series started in the 1960's.

Comment: Thanks. I really didn't have much to go on, but your answer was perfect.

Comment: glad to be of service. Have to admit it was simply dumb luck on my part!

Comment: Well, my comment 'there were just a ton of them' definitely fits, as it is the largest series in existence per the wikipedia.

Comment: Most recent release - 2019 - This series is still going?  That has to be some kind of record...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: It definitely is. Most recent issue is #3071, "Xirashos Tiefen", released 2020-06-26. The next one is due tomorrow. One per week. Since 1961. It *is* pulp SciFi, mind you, some of the issues are pretty crap to be honest and continuity was not always perfect, but the length of the run makes it special in its very own way. If you pick up a current issue and just start reading, you will have *no* idea what they are talking about, as the in-universe story had been built continuously...

Answer (score 10):

As confirmed by the OP in comments, this was the [*Perry Rhodan*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?19673) series.

[Wikipedia says of the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan):

> The first 126 novels (plus five novels of the spinoff series *Atlan*) were translated into English and published by Ace Books between 1969 and 1978

And [describes the basic plot as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan#Universe_and_multiverse):

> The story line starts in 1971 with the first manned moon landing by U.S. Space Force Major Perry Rhodan and his crew, who discover a marooned extraterrestrial space ship from the (fictional) planet Arkon in the (real) M13 cluster. Appropriating the Arkonide technology, they proceed to unify Terra and carve out a place for humanity in the galaxy and the cosmos. (The concepts for two of the technical accomplishments that enable them to do so—positronic brains and starship drives for near-instantaneous hyperspatial translation—are direct adoptions from Isaac Asimov's science fiction universe.)
>
> As the series progresses, major characters, including the title character, are granted relative immortality. It is relative in the sense that they are immune to age and disease, but could suffer a violent death. The story continues over the course of millennia, including flashbacks thousands and even millions of years into the past, and the scope widens to encompass other galaxies, extremely remote parts of space, parallel universes and weirder cosmic structures, time travel, paranormal powers, weird/cute/aggressive aliens and bodyless entities (some with sheer god-like powers).

The first few English translations appeared with these covers:

[image: Cover of Perry Rhodan #1: Enterprise Stardust]
[image: Cover of Perry Rhodan #2: The Radiant Dome]
[image: Cover of Perry Rhodan #3: Galatic Alarm]
[image: Cover of Perry Rhodan #4: Invasion from Space]

Comment: That's another series where I would go to the bookstore, and all they'd have was like #5, #17, #23... so I never bought any.

Comment: I was lucky in my book store. It was money I lacked.